# How to create a round badge to show number, which is responsive to font size?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Is there any way to create a round badge to show a number, which the round badge and number are responsive to font size?

I tried:

```html
<input type="range" min="30" max="100" value="30" onchange="document.getElementById('d').style.fontSize=this.value+'px';"><br/>
<div id="d" style="position:relative;display:inline-block;font-size:30px;">
  <div style="position:relative;color:red;zoom:400%;">&#9679;</div>
  <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px;">
    <table style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;top:0px;left:0px;text-align:center;font-size:inherit;">
      <tr><td>10</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

The slider would update the font size of parent div,so the size of badge and number would also update. It looks very similar to the thing I want, but it has a problem: the text always shift to top a bit, no matter how I set the margin and padding. Is there any way to fix the visual position issue? Or is there any similar way to create such responsive round badge with number in center?

Comment: Why inline, why tables?

Answer (score 0):

For a centered circle use this centered bullet `&#8226;` instead of black circle `&#9679;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use flexbox, it's great for aligning things:

```css
.badge {
  font-size: 48px;
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
.badge p {
  font-size: 1em;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="badge">
<p>
1
</p>
</div>
<input type="range" min="30" max="100" value="30" onchange="document.querySelector('.badge').style.fontSize=this.value+'px';"><br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simplify a bit the markup and use a custom property to change the size of both the font-size and red circle , e.g.

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PerJLL?editors=0010)

---

**Markup**

```
<input type="range" min="30" max="100" value="30" aria-controls="d">

<div id="d">
  <span>10</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
:root { --size: 30px; }

#d { 
  font-size: var(--size);
  margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

#d span {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 10px;
  height: var(--size);
  width: var(--size);
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red; }
```

**Javascript**

```
var ctrl = document.querySelector('[aria-controls]');
var dde = document.documentElement;
ctrl.addEventListener('change',  function() {
   dde.style.setProperty('--size', this.value + 'px');
});
```